# Showing field name in the attribute table, not alias, in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, fields-attributes, alias

I have a file geodatabase table added to QGIS. How can I show field name, not alias in the attribute table? (Or delete the aliases)

In ArcMap I can set it in Layer Properties

[image]

The name, set in ArcGIS is F20, QGIS displays the alias "20":

[image]

Comment: How did you get aliases from a file GDB ? when I add data from a file gdb (using the OpenFileGDB driver on QGIS 3.16.4) I only see the field name and not the alias (and in the field tab of the layer properties alias field are empty)

Comment: try to open the layer properties in QGIS and in the field tab delete the alias (or set it to the same as the field name) it could work

Comment: @J.R QGIS 3.20.2 shows alias name as in the image.

Comment: I cant edit the field aliases (or anything in the fgdb table, maybe I'm missing the driver)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Open "Layer Properties -> Attribute Form"
- Delete aliases.

[image]

This works just in the project and doesn't change the layer source.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the information displayed in the attribute table without having to delete all the alias for each field, you can also play with the `export features` options. For instance, I have a layer ("collect", as a .gpkg file) with :

- a field name `tillage_type` and its alias `Type de travail du sol`
- list of values for that field (e.g. `superficial_tillage`) together with a description for each value (e.g. `travail du sol superficiel ~5cm)`

[image: attribute form screen shot]

When you right click on that layer (from the layer pane) < export < save features as, this opens the export layer options. To export your layer with different QGis display options you can play with the 2 checkbox `use aliases as exported name` or `replace raw values of selected field by displayed values`.

[image]

The initial attribute table was the following :

[image]

After checking/applying the `replace raw values of selected field by displayed values` option, I get the following.

[image]

Note 1 : I haven't tested that for every file extension but I think the result might differ depending on this. I have seen differences when exporting to .shp file.

Note 2 : I think that regardless of the alias (for field name) and the value description (for each field's value), when you import the resulting file in another software, only raw values and field name will be displayed (not alias or value descriptions). For me this was the case when importing my geopackage file into Python as a GeoDataFrame.